# Quantitative Proteomic Analysis : ANOVA or MANOVA?

Tags: anova, biostatistics, manova

So, this may be a really dumb question but I'd rather ask it now than 3 weeks later when I'm neck deep into problems. The title is kind of self-explanatory but I'll expand a bit :

I've been tasked of doing Proteomic analysis for one of our team's project. That's already a first for me, and while I've done plenty of basic statistical analysis, I've never done it in such huge dataset.

We have 3 groups : Treatment A, Treatment B and Control.

For each group, we have n=5 pair of samples. What I mean by that is that the team basically took 2 samples for each 5 individuals of each groups at the same time (imagine if it's a lung biopsy, they would have taken a biopsy from the left lung and from the right lung for each individual).

Now, the samples have been processed, they're gonna send me the data matrix and we agreed on the fact that there shouldn't be any difference between samples from the same individual (there is no reason to assume the proteins in the left lung sample would be different from the right lung sample), so I'm going to calculate the average for each individual on each protein. That should be easy enough.

The hard part will be the group comparisons. I'll need to know for each protein whether the average quantity is different between group or not.

My first thought was ANOVA. I have 3 independant groups and I'm looking at a response variable (the quantity of a given protein).

But with the THOUSANDS of proteins that will be compared, I'm not sure anymore.

So in the case of a comparisons between 3 groups that involves several response variables, wouldn't a one-way MANOVA be a better fit for such analysis ?

Basically the matrix would look like that :

```
| Protein    | Group A    | Group B    | Group C    |

| :--------: | :--------: | :--------: | :--------: |

| Protein 1  |            |            |            |
| Protein 2  |            |            |            |
| ...        |            |            |            |
| Protein n  |            |            |            |
```

Sorry for rambling (and maybe making it even more confusing for you) and thanks in advance for the answers

Comment: How are you going to choose the significance level $\alpha$ such that it is scientifically meaningful? You're not going to pick some arbitrary number (e.g. 0.05) I hope.

Comment: @Galen Why ? What's wrong with a significance level of 0.05 as long as we use a correction when doing the multiple pairwise comparison ?

Comment: Multiple correction aims to address family-wise error rates. It doesn't help you if your decision boundary is arbitrary. Introducing arbitrary choices into an analysis makes the results more arbitrary.

Comment: @Galen Well, aren't most boundary decision arbitrary anyway ? I know that the weaker the statistical power and sample size, the higher the significance level should be, but I don't know of any specific formula to calculcate the proper/optimum α =/

Comment: I'm not sure whether most decision boundaries are arbitrary, hopefully not, but I don't see the relevance of that proposition either way. Although I don't know if it was what you meant, it gives the appearance of an argument like, "most things have this quality issue, so why not make one more thing with this quality issue?". It doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: There is usually, if not always, a tradeoff between statistical power $1- \beta$ and the type 1 error rate $\alpha$ when doing null hypothesis significance testing. They are both affected by sample size. Another ingredient is the effect size, which is where there is the most hope of finding something scientifically meaningful.

Comment: There often isn't a ready-made formula for computing $\alpha$ for a given statistical inference. Sometimes you can derive such formulae yourself, but I find it is more often feasible to do computational simulations. This still leaves it on the shoulders of the analyst to decide what meaningful criterion they are optimising $\alpha$ for; preferably something meaningful to the science.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of problem has been around for decades, at least since the development of microarray technology allowed evaluation of expression of thousands of different genes from the same samples.

If your proteomic data have already been reduced from mass-spectral or other raw data to protein abundances, the tools originally developed for microarray data, like the [`limma` Bioconductor package](https://doi.org/doi:10.18129/B9.bioc.limma), might well be applied directly. [This web page](https://pnnl-comp-mass-spec.github.io/proteomics-data-analysis-tutorial/DEA.html) illustrates its use with some wrapper functions that seem to be designed specifically for proteomics (although I haven't looked into them). This approach deals with the problems in unreliable variance estimates from small numbers of samples and the multiple-comparison corrections needed when there are thousands of hypothesis tests. It might be best if you evaluated the expression values separately rather than averaging each pair of samples, as that will improve your ability to estimate the underlying variances.

[Bioconductor](https://bioconductor.org) provides a wealth of other tools for all aspects of proteomic analysis.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer ! I've heard of the limma tool but never had to use it before, I'll go check that. And you're absolutely right, keeping each sample separated instead of averaging the pair should definitely work, Thanks again !